# Can I use font-awesome without downloading?

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

For some simple html pages I want to use Fontaweseome without downloading it at all.

I was thinking to have my CSS to point to the /fontFace like this:

(i.e.: directly to the github URL)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

which I did ... but it does not seem to work.

No errors yet something like this:

```
 <i class="icon-bar"></i>
```

where

```
  <style>
  i { font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif; }
  </style>
```

is not rendered as expected

Comment: @YaMo thanks but it still does not work ... I will edit my question to improve clarity

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Font Awesome is included in Bootstrap's CDN. You just need to add the below link in your head section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and that's it, you can enjoy your icons. You shouldn't need to use font-face or call it in the styles anywhere, just add the appropriate classes to your 'i' tags in the usual way like:

```
<i class="fa fa-download"></i>
```

see http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Comment: if you use font-family important! it overrides Fa

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your font-face declaration is incorrect, it should be:

```
@font-face { ... }
```

Then to call it in your CSS, you will need to add something like:

```
i { 
    font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif; 
}
```

or

```
icon-bar { 
    font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ... I was mistaken in testing it

Answer (score 4):

> I want to use Fontaweseome without downloading it at all.
>   (i.e.: directly to the github URL)

If you're going to use *any* third-party code in this way, you should make sure you have permission from the owner of the site you're downloading it from. Some sites will block external links like this to because of the bandwidth costs it would incur. I believe GitHub is one of those sites -- if they allowed this, it would cost them a huge amount of money to serve all the javascript and other code.

However, there are sites around that *do* provide this service. They are known as CDNs. For example, [Google's CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) is a well known one, which a lot of people use for libraries such as jQuery.

I don't think Google's CDN serves FontAwesome at this time, but that's the direction you need to be looking; there may well be a CDN that does provide FontAwesome. I don't know of one off the top of my head, but [a quick search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fontawesome+cdn) might give you some leads.

Failing that, I don't really see a problem with downloading the files yourself. Even if it's a small site, it's probably less effort than asking the question here.

Comment: I think referring to github.io/ sites is okay from GitHub

Answer (score 2):

You can use Font Awesome CDN embed code! Get it here:

http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Maybe this option was not available in the time of asking this question.